# Curves with order of contact $n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry

> Definition: Let $\alpha: I \mapsto \mathbb{R^3}$ and $\beta: \overline{I} \mapsto \mathbb{R^3}$ be two regular curves such that $\alpha(t_0) = \beta(t_0)$, where $t_0 \in I \cap \overline{I}$. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are said to have contact of order $n$ at $t_0$ ($n$ being an integer $\geq 1$) if all derivatives of order $\leq n$ of the functions $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are equal at $t_0$ and derivatives of order $n + 1$ are different.
>
> Let $\alpha(t) = (t, y(t), 0)$ and $\overline{\alpha}(t) = (t, \overline{y}(t), 0)$, $t \in I$  be two regular curves with order of contact $n$ at $t_0 \in I$. Prove that:
>
> a) If $n$ is odd, there is a neighborhood $J \subset I$ of $t_0$ such that $\forall t \in J$, $y(t) - \overline{y}(t)$ doesn't change sign, as shown below.
>
> [image]
>
> b) If $n$ is even, there exist $t_1$ and $t_2 \in I$ such that $y(t_1) - \overline{y}(t_1) < 0$ and $y(t_2) - \overline{y}(t_2) > 0$, as shown below.
>
> [image]

To be honest I don't have a clue how to go about solving this. My only strategies were expanding $y$ and $\overline{y}$ in terms of their Taylor series and see if there were any insights there... alas, there weren't. I'd appreciate any help. How do I start solving this?

Comment: Looking at the Taylor series is precisely the correct approach. Maybe you should look at the Taylor series for $(y-\bar y)(t)$. By the way, "all" derivatives of order $n+1$?

Comment: Alright, writing $$y(t) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac{y^k(t_0)}{k!}(t-t_0)^k + \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{y^k(t_0)}{k!}(t-t_0)^k$$
and  $$\overline{y}(t) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac{\overline{y}^k(t_0)}{k!}(t-t_0)^k + \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{\overline{y}^k(t_0)}{k!}(t-t_0)^k$$

we have $$(y-\overline{y})(t) = \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{y^k(t_0)}{k!}(t-t_0)^k - \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{\overline{y}^k(t_0)}{k!}(t-t_0)^k$$

since the other terms will cancel out ($n$ equal derivatives). Where do I go now? It doesn't seem clear how this won't change sign/or the case in b) will happen.

Comment: @TedShifrin you're right, "all" derivatives or order $n+1$ was a mistake, I didn't notice it at the time. Thanks for the correction, I've edited it now.

Comment: OK, so how 'bout using the $(n+1)$st Taylor polynomial with remainder? :P

Comment: @TedShifrin Do you mean writing it like this?:

$$(y - \overline{y})(t) = \frac{(y^{n+1}(t_0) - \overline{y}^{n+1}(t_0))(t-t_0)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} + R$$

I still don't know what this tells me about $(y-\bar{y})(t)$, though.

Comment: Well, you're missing the factor of $(t-t_0)^{n+1}$? :)

Comment: You're right, damn, gotta be more careful. Though I still don't know what I can conclude from this.

Comment: Well, reread the question and think. And, of course, for $|t-t_0|$ small, the $R$ term is (relatively) inconsequential, right?

Comment: @TedShifrin Well, I'm supposed to show (at least in a)) that either $y > \bar{y}$ or $\bar{y} > y$. The $R$ term doesn't really matter here, I agree. But it will either be the case that $y^{n+1}(t_0) > \bar{y}^{n+1}(t_0)$ or $\bar{y}^{n+1}(t_0) > y^{n+1}(t_0)$. And since all that's determining the sign of $y - \bar{y}$ is that term $(y^{n+1}(t_0) - \overline{y}^{n+1}(t_0))$, then at a neighborhood of $t_0$, the $R$ doesn't matter and $(y - \bar{y})(t)$ won't change sign. Is this correct? I don't know how to prove b), though.

Comment: Pay more attention. The sign of $t-t_0$ will matter when $n$ is ... ?

Comment: @TedShifrin The sign of $(t - t_0)$ will matter if $n$ is even, the case in b). In that case, can we assume that there will be a neighborhood of $t_0$ where $y^{n+1} > \bar{y}^{n+1}$, and then another neighborhood where the opposite would happen, leading to a different sign in each case and then the exercise is solved?

Comment: You're not saying it right. Neighborhoods are two-sided. What should you say instead?

Comment: Oh yes, I see the mistake. I should say "on one side of the neighborhood, $y^{n+1}(t_0) > \bar{y}^{n+1}(t_0)$, and on another, $y^{n+1}(t_0) < \bar{y}^{n+1}(t_0)$, so that in each case $(y - \bar{y})(t)$ has different sign, and the conclusion asked for in $b)$ follows". Is this alright?

Comment: Yup :) Taylor's Theorem for the win ... again :) And no sign change when $n$ is odd.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's great to live in a time where discussions like these with people like you can happen. One couldn't ask for more.

Comment: You're welcome, @Matheus. I try to be as stubborn as possible :) I would have enjoyed teaching you in person :)